# ASP.NET CORE: Database Connection Issue (SQLite) in Production

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, sqlite

OS: Linux, CentOS
Proxy: Apache
Asp.NET Core 1.1

Problem: I got to a certain moment with my app when I decided to deploy it on the real server.

**So everything worked and works perfectly fine on my local machine. I have no issues.**

But when I published it and uploaded to the server it doesn’t work the way I expected. And I mean specifically the database (SQLite). **The app reads data from the db as it supposed to**, but whenever there is  await _db.SaveChangesAsync() in my code the app crashes.

I have searched all over the internet and didn’t anything that would help me.

So far I have 3 different Exceptions:

1. SQLite Error 8: ‘attempt to write a readonly database’.
2. I changed the permissions of the db file to 777 as well as the folder it self, doesn’t help.

Got this: 
SQLite Error 14: ‘unable to open database file’.

3. When I tried to add this to Configure:

   app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
               {
                   ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
               });

got this exemption:
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeadersMiddleware[1]
      Parameter count mismatch between X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto.

Connection String is :

"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=GlobalEvent.db"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the wrong reverse proxy settings. I couldn't find the correct solution for Apache, so I changed it to Nginx. To be honest I actually love it even more. Now everything works. Also, I created Nginx server blocks for subdomains. Everything else from above still applies.

Here is my conf file for ASP.NET Core app:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/subdomain.domain.com/html;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com www.subdomain.domain.com;  
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```